# Querying a sparse multidimensional dataset

Tags: database, multidimensional-array, indexing

We have a dataset containing entities with tags. Each tag is a string, and each entity can have up to 3 tags associated with it.

We would like to implement an index to enable fast queries of which tags co-occur most often with a given set of tags. For example, I might have the following entities:

```
Entity 1 - tags A, B, Z
Entity 2 - tags B, C, E
Entity 3 - tags A, B, Y
Entity 4 - tags A, E, F
```

The tag that co-occurs most often with A is B (2 times). The tags that co-occur most often with A and B are Y and Z (one time each).

Our dataset is fairly small (about 2000 items) and the 2000-dimensional space it represents is very sparse, so this can no doubt be implemented with acceptable performance by just partitioning the data by tag and then enumerating the entities to find the most common tags. However, I'm interested if there is a particular index type that would handle this type of problem efficiently for large datasets.

Comment: By the term "co-occur most often", you mean that the other tag(s) occur(s) with the given tag on the more entities than any other tag(s)?
I am not sure I get this right as B occurs only twice with A, but you refer that as 3.

Comment: I suppose is typo.

Comment: Yes sorry I mistyped it. Corrected now.

Comment: If the dataset is small, why do you want to create an index? Simply compute the values as you read the data.

Comment: Because I think the dataset will get much bigger in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

1) The tags are in alphabetical order in the entities.

2) An entity can comprise at least 1 tag and at most 3 tags (you actually stated that)

3) An entity is non-unique

4) A tag is unique

5) A co-occurrence can be of 2 tags or of 3 (stated above)

6) A tag pair in the second and third position of an entity is a co-occurrence that you wish to index

7) You are able to use an RDBMS, e.g. MySQL

Two tables - Entity and Tag.  See MySQL syntax table creation statements below.

Tag has a unique index on it.

Entity is indexed by 2 multi-column (or concatenated) indices such that you may search from left to right: e.g. on (tag1), or (tag1 AND tag2), or (tag1 AND tag2 AND tag3), or (tag2 and tag3).  See explanation at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

The multi-column index allows you to rapidly address all co-occurrences using a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM entity
  WHERE tag1='A'
  AND tag2='B' 
  AND tag3='C';

SELECT count(*) AS count, tag2, tag3 FROM entity
  GROUP BY tag2, tag3
  ORDER BY count DESC;

CREATE TABLE entity (
    entity_name  CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    tag1         CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    tag2         CHAR(30) NULL,
    tag3         CHAR(30) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (entity_name),
    INDEX tags  (tag1, tag2, tag3),
    INDEX tags2 (tag2, tag3)
);

CREATE TABLE tag (
    tag          CHAR(30) NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (tag)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

One record gives 3 pairs [(1,2), (2,3), (1,3)] with one element and 3 pairs [((1,2), 3), ((1,3), 2), ((2,3),1)] with two elements. Total only 6 pairs.
If you want fast select you can just save it with counters.

In common case (N(tags) > 3, N = ?), I suppose, you could build tag's tree: all tags is sorted by name, each node - one tag, edge means you have entities with both tags, weight - counter.
So you need O(N) iteration to go from root of your request to last tag and find min(weight) (N - tag's chain size of query). And O(N) to past new tag's chain, if you start from root tag (N - tag's chain size of insert).

More traditional way you see in RustyB answer, using multi column indexes for you DB. Just note in most cases it is not efficient to store something as strings (or varchars) in RDBMS (if it could be numeric using dirs), because read/write strings are slow, if you don't need always read rows with tags. For this task, I think, is true for all DB, because indexes for integer values and comparison of integers are commonly faster then for chars.